# How do I Alter an attribute to change its datatype in Object type?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I Alter an attribute to change its datatype in an Object type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `ALTER TYPE` statement, and specifically for the [alter attribute definition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/alter_type.htm#i2112566) clause. For example, to change the type of an attribute to NUMBER from something else you'd use

```
ALTER TYPE MY_TYPE
  MODIFY ATTRIBUTE SOME_ATTRIBUTE NUMBER;
```

Share and enjoy.